# Range dimension ranges, ATG-Endeca 11.2 appication

Tags: oracle, range, dimensions, atg, endeca

What is the best way to define standard ranges for a range dimension?

Using RangeDimensionExporter will let you have auto generated ranges or not fully custom ranges.

Ranges are defined like *:5,,5:10,,.... letting you set the length of the range after specific values.

What I need is set ranges like 
Less than 10 
10-50 
51-200 
201 and above

Is there a way to make the above configuration work like this or the only option is to configure dirrectly the xml and inject it in CAS dimval recordstore?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is the only way to add custom range OOTB. This can be achieved to customized RangeDimension exporter and pass custom range.

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Ajay

Comment: Thank you Ajay for confirming that this is the oob way  and anything different would require a custom solution.

Comment: Hi Ajay. I was thinking of using an accessor to create the ranges instead of the OOTB components. Simple logic.. check the value of the desired property.. if is greater than X return a String "greater than X" and so on. Do you see any drawbacks or dark spots with this approach?